# Android: How to host media player as a service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-service-binding

I have an app with a playlist and a media player UI.

The issue I am having is when I am playing music, and I re-enter the activity (using a menu), it restarts the media file (because it is calling the onCreate method from the top).

I need to implement the mediaplayer as a servive instead but I have no idea on how to do this! Everywhere I look online is just non-relevant and super confusing articles/code.

Can anyone assist with helpful tutorials or articles related to this?

My code can be found here: https://github.com/becausewesley/MusicalStructureApp

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Answer (score 3):

This article [Creating Media player service](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/) shows step by step on how you can implement a service to create a Mediaplayer application to run in the background. Hope this helps!